# Can't Create Riot Account

Tags: valorant

As the title states, I tried to create a riot games account to play Valorant. But when I head to valorant's website, it gets stuck after I enter my password. I tried refreshing the page 5 times and tried more than 10 times until now, but still can't. When I head to riot games official website, the sign up takes me to League Of Legends NA thing and I don't know about it.  Can anyone help me create a riot games account?

Comment: Do you have any extensions in your browser that are blocking JavaScript? Any firewall rules preventing part of the page from loading? Any errors in your browser when the page loads?

Comment: Not at all, I don't have anything blocking and everything is fine.

Comment: The riot games account would connect you/enable you to play all of their games, it may be trying to default take you to sign up on what looks like LoL but after signing up you don't have to install it, you can just install/play Valorant

Comment: Makes sense, Thank you, I will try then update you.

Answer (score -1):

to the guy who cant get it working. I had the same thing happen to me but the way I fixed it was clicking one of the three thnig like google,facebook,apple. try clicking one of those. the one that worked for me was google.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).